# Calculate third derivative

Tags: calculus, differential

I need to calculate $\dfrac{d^3y}{dx^3}$, where $y = t^3$ and $x = e^{-t}$, basically I don't get how to use n-th differential formula when we also have x as function, could someone explain me this ?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.nabla.hr/Z_MemoHU-104.htm for the most general case of parametric equations.

Comment: @Kevin Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

We have that:
$$\frac {dy}{dt}=3t^2$$
$$x=e^{-t} \implies x'=\frac {dx}{dt}=-e^{-t}$$
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {dy}{dt}\frac {dt}{dx}=\frac 1 {-e^{-t}}\frac {dy}{dt} =-{3t^2} {e^{t}} $$
$$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac {d(3t^2e^{t})}{dt}\frac {dt}{dx}=3te^{2t}(t+2) $$
$$.....$$
I let you finish..

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have that

- $x = e^{-t}\implies t=-\ln x\implies y=-\ln^3 x$